# процедура повышающая рейтинг заказчику SQl

Tags: sql, sql-server

Суть вопроса такова: 
есть БД , таблицы, которые понадобятся:

```
customer:

id_customer
name_customer
.... 
rating_customer  INT CHECK,
(rating_customer IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)),

Delivery:
id_delivery
date_delivery
.....
price

order_list:
id_order
id_customer
....
```

Нужно создать , скорее всего процедуру, которая будет высчитывать скидку, выводя конечную сумму price, скидка вычисляется по уровню rating (таблица customer), список скидок: 
уровень 1- 1%
уровень 2-3%
уровень 3 - 5%
уровень 4 -7%
уровень 5 -10%

Рейтинг высчитывается от кол-ва заказов customer, если кол-во заказов > 5 , то rating +1.

Если коротко, то рейтинг от 1-5 (накручивается, когда кол-во заказов кратно 5).
в зависимости от рейтинга выходит скидка на заказ.
у меня есть часть процедуры, которая высчитывает скидку, но как сделать процедуру по накрутке рейтинга и добавить ее в процедуру скидок, я не знаю, помогите , пожалуйста. надеюсь я все подробно описала) 
спасибо!

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE discount (IN /// INT)
 COMMENT 'процедура высчитывающая скидку заказчику'
 begin
     IF (( rating_customer>=1) && (rating_customer<2)) THAN
        SELECT price*0.01 FROM delivery WHERE/////
        ELSIF ((rating_customer>=2) && (rating_customer<3)) THAN
        SELECT price*0.03 FROM delivery WHERE/////
        ELSIF ((rating_customer>=3) && (rating_customer<4)) THAN
        SELECT price*0.05 FROM delivery WHERE/////
        ELSIF ((rating_customer>=4) && (rating_customer<5)) THAN
        SELECT price*0.07 FROM delivery WHERE/////
        ELSIF (rating_customer==5)  THAN
        SELECT price*0.1 FROM delivery WHERE/////
        SELECT price FROM delivery WHERE/////
        END IF;
    end
//
```

Comment: Вы лучше создайте таблицу скидок (мин_кол_заказов, макс_кол_заказов, коэфф_цены), соответственно со значениями типа (0, 4 ,1), (5, 9, 0.99), ...,(20, 24, 0.93), (25, 9999, 0.9). Станет в разы проще. Особенно если потребуется таблицу скидок изменить...

Comment: как вариант, да, но нужно , что бы автоматически поднимался рейтинг заказчика и от этого уже появлялась скидка.

Comment: *нужно , что бы автоматически поднимался рейтинг заказчика* Нафига? Если надо его отображать на странице - ну считайте дополнительно ROUNDDOWN(COUNT(orders) / 5)